# JS clearInterval() will not clear

Tags: javascript, clearinterval

Just moments ago I asked a question about why my setInterval() function would only run once,

[JS setInterval() only runs once when animating opacity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19371647/js-setinterval-only-runs-once-when-animating-opacity)

I had that answered, but then I wanted to check and make sure the loop stopped, so I added an alert() to the loop and found out clearInterval is not clearing even though I initially ran the setInterval function connected to a global variable...

the opacity change works fine, but now the alert box goes on infinitely after you click OK... eventually I won't need the alert function I just wanted to see if the interval actually cleared which it doesn't...

```
var run;
var runOpt;

document.getElementById('menu-1-A').style.opacity=0;
document.getElementById('menu-1-B').style.opacity=0;

function openSubMenu1(item) {
    runOpt=item;
    run = setInterval(runSubMenu1,35);
}

function runSubMenu1()  {

    var i=document.getElementById('menu-1-'+runOpt);

    if (parseInt(i.style.opacity) == 1) {
      clearInterval(run);
      alert('done');

    } else {
      i.style.opacity = parseFloat(i.style.opacity) + .1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you calling `openSubMenu1` multiple times?

Comment: Can u create js fiddle?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you plalx -- openSubMenu1() was run from onmouseover which was repeatedly calling openSubMenu1(), I created a variable to test if the menu is open, if it is openSubMenu1() returns false before calling setInterval()..

now it only runs once. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

What may be happening is that you are starting multiple instances before the first setInterval has finished, so the clearTimeout has the wrong reference when called.

The following uses closures instead of globals so each call has its own timeout reference:

```
<div id="d0">jere</div>

<script>

var makeOpaque = (function() {
  var timeout, el;

  return function(id) {

    if (!el) {
      el = document.getElementById(id);
      timeout = setInterval(makeOpaque, 50)

    } else if (el && el.style.opacity < 1) {
      el.style.opacity = +el.style.opacity + 0.1;

      // debug
      console.log(el.id + ' : ' + el.style.opacity);

    } else {
      timeout && clearInterval(timeout);
      alert('done');
    }
  }
}());

makeOpaque('d0');
```